# Solving for $x$: $1=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, problem-solving, infinity, continued-fractions

How can I solve for $x$:

$$1=\cfrac{1}{x}+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{x}}+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{x}}}+\cdots$$

Any clues?

Comment: does the rhs converge for any $x$?

Comment: Some quick calculations lead me to believe that the series does not converge, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Each term can be written as $\frac{a+bx}{c+dx}$ where $a,b,c,d$ are Fibonacci numbers. I'll need a little moment to figure out which they are.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $\displaystyle \frac{F_nx+F_{n-1}}{F_{n+1}x+F_n}$ starting at $n=0$ I believe. (typo)

Answer (score 13):

We deal with a function $x\mapsto \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$, which if we take $\frac{1}{x}$ as argument, we should rather write as $x\mapsto \frac{1}{1+x}$.

Iterated, this gives the [fixed point iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_iteration) for finding a soltion of $\frac{1}{1+x}=x$. And therefore all your terms eventually turn out converge to a solution of $1=(1+x)\ x$, namely $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ (see [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)), making the total sum diverge.

Some [Mathematica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica) code:

[image]

Comment: Do the terms ever converge to $-\varphi$ besides $x=-\varphi$?

Comment: @anon: $|\varphi|\approx 0.618<1$, so the result is positive. There is no square, the $x$ on the right hand side of $\frac{1}{1+x}=x$ is dropped.

Comment: @vermiculus: eww, why did you do that? ;P

Comment: @NickKidman Hehehehehe Hey man, if people vote it up, it ought to be persistent.  It'd be nice to see a formal proof, even though the original equation is a *definition* for $\phi$, but a table --- while not conclusive --- has immediate and observable value.  (What  would be *better* to *see* is a graph of these data.)

Comment: @vermiculus: Okay, I see. Well I've improved on the pic now. On your request, I tried to make a plot, but since starting input like $x=1000$ hops to the tiny $\frac{1}{1001}$ after only one iteration and then stays in a range of $(0,1)$, the plot isn't particularly pretty. I could cancel the first value, but still, not spectacular, if you ask me.

Comment: If you use a code block for your code, other people could copy and paste it easily. It would also look better.

Comment: @Lucas: Noted! But as you maybe read, I initially didn't even post the code in the answer itself.

Comment: I did, it just seems more difficult to do, and worse look and interact with.

Comment: I wonder was this answer has so many upvote. It does not answer the question while the one of nbubis does.

Comment: @GillesBonnet: How does it not answer the question? I show that all terms in the sum tend towards a constant value, no matter what would-be x you start with. And I write that therefore the total sum diverges. You could add "and hence the problem "1=..." isn't well posed, there is no solution", or what are you missing? I don't mind if you improve the answer. Or first person talk.

Comment: @NikolajK: My comments was not constructive and rude. You have all the reasons to be offended. I apologize deeply. I understand what you say. I agree that the point is that the terms of the series are all positive and tend to the golden ration, hence the RHS diverges for any $x$ and the equation has no solution. I think this is what you basically say but it did not appear to me clear when I read your answer. I don't really get what you mean in your first sentence. I think the use of the variable $x$ is kind of misleading here because it seems to be a different use then the $x$ of the question.

Comment: @NikolajK: As personal taste I would give the "strategy" of the proof right at the beginning. Something like "We will see that the term of the series on the RHS are positive and converges to a strictly positive value independent of $x$, hence the RHS always diverges and there is no solution".

Comment: @GillesBonnet: It's true that it's shorter than it has to be. If you really case, again, feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 12):

$$a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{1+a_n},\ a_0=1/x,\ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n=1$$

Unfortunately, $a_n$ converges to a non zero constant $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$, so that the sum of all $a_n$'s is infinity.